# How to define a has_many through relationship with FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm trying to get to grips with TDD in Rails. I'm sure this is a very noob question, but here goes.

I have the following models

```
class User
  has_many :users_roles
  has_many :roles, :through => :users_roles
end

class Role
  has_many :users_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :users_roles
end

class UserRole
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

I have a seed.rb that generates the Roles used by the app.

```
Role.create([
  { :name => "Admin" },
  { :name => "User" }
])
```

I'm using Factory Girl, and trying to define a user with a role. I've tried numerous approaches, and referred to other questions on SO and other sources, but nothing seems to fit me set up.

The factory currently looks like this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "User_Email_#{n}@example.com" }
    trait :is_admin do 
      association roles << Role.find_by_name("Admin") 
    end
  end
end
```

How to I create a User with an associated Role within FactoryGirl, given that (a) they have a has_many through relationship, and (b) the role already exists in the database, and does not need to be created by FactoryGirl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a has_many association like any other attribute:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "User_Email_#{n}@example.com" }
    trait :is_admin do
      roles { [Role.find_by_name("Admin")] }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One variant is

```
factory :admin_user do
  roles { [ Role.find_by_name("Admin") ] }
end
```

but this does not allow to create user with several roles

another variant is:
you can try smth like this

```
trait :is_admin do 
  after(:build) do |user|
    user.roles << Role.find_by_name("Admin") 
    # or 
    # user.roles = user.roles + [Role.find_by_name("Admin")]
  end
end
```

I am not sure if `<<` works for built (not saved) object.